# Using free() on a copy of the actual pointer is acceptable / correct?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

Is this:

```
int *a = malloc (sizeof (int) );
int *b = a;
free (b);
```

the same as this:

```
int *a = malloc (sizeof (int) );
free (a);
```

If yes, no need to explain, but if no, please elaborate why not!

Comment: Why do you think yes? Why do you think no?

Comment: I think this is possible since, at least in my head, all that both 'a' and 'b' contain are addresses, so once the free function gets either on or the other makes no difference (again, if all they contain are addresses). Whatsoever my doubt comes from the fact that I called malloc for a and not for b specifically, because I don't know exactly how these functions work I had some doubts if the very variable that I used for the malloc somehow influenced the free function. Basically I had no idea why it wouldn't work but because I know so little of these functions I wanted to make sure this worked!

Comment: @CarlosPinto In that case, you need to know why it does work, right?

Comment: You don't free *b*, you free the *object* **where it points to** . and it happens to point to the same *object* as *a* does.

Comment: But I guess it makes sense, as malloc doesn't even receive them as arguments, so it can't possibly be influenced by them right?

Comment: It works because malloc gives the address of the allocated memory to a, I copy that address to b, and then free the memory b is pointing to, which is exactly the same that a is pointing to, is this correct?

Comment: @CarlosPinto: Yes.  Just be aware that if you `free(b)`, then you *don't* want to `free(a)` afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that `free(x)` is the same as `free(y)` when `x == y` has nothing to do with the `free()` function. This is simply due to the fact that `free()` is a function. In C, any function's arguments are passed by value. So for any function `f`, `f(x)` is equivalent to `f(y)` so long as `y == x`.

As an aside, this is not necessarily true for function-like macros, that may look like functions, but are not in fact. So if you have a macro such as:

```
#define myfunc(x) do_something(&x)
```

then `myfunc(x)` will almost certainly have a different result from `myfunc(y)` even if `x == y`, because the *true* function is `do_something()`, and the arguments being passed to it `&x` and `&y`. Even if `x` equals `y`, `&x` does not equal `&y`, so the arguments being passed to the function are not in fact equal in value and the behavior of the function is therefore expected to be different.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are equivalent.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.3, (*emphasis mine*)

> The `free` function causes the **space pointed to by `ptr`** to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the
>   behavior is undefined.

So, as long as you pass the same `ptr` value (the pointer itself or a copy of it) which was earlier returned by `malloc()` or family, you're good to go.

Comment: I would also highlight the word *value* here: *"So, as long as you pass the same `ptr` **value**..."*

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'm pretty new to memory allocation, hence my basic question, this means that I can free from within a function as long as I pass the address as an argument, correct?

Comment: @CarlosPinto Yes, you certainly can.