# Confused about C pointer freeing

Tags: c

I am confused about following code, can someone clear it up for me?

when i do:

```
char *a = malloc(10);
char *c = a;
free(c);
```

does it free the c pointer itself or the address which it is pointing to? (which is a which is malloced address).

Or does it free the a pointer and leave the malloced address alone?

Comment: You don't free the **pointer**! And you never free an address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using free() on a copy of the actual pointer is acceptable / correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43456215/using-free-on-a-copy-of-the-actual-pointer-is-acceptable-correct)

Answer (score 4):

You never "free a pointer". That's just a very sloppy shorthand that new users pick up all to easily from other sloppy former new users and never really question.

You allocate memory and you free memory. The way you talk about that memory is via a pointer to it, but the memory is the resource, not any pointer that describes the memory.

Since you talk about the memory via pointers, pointers are what `malloc` returns and what `free` takes, and because the deallocation function is called like the verb "free", and the deallocation function takes a pointer, it's an easy misstep down the slippery slope to start talking about "freeing a pointer". It's a similar misstep to speak "owning a pointer"; what is really owned is the responsibility for the resource.

Comment: You can free a pointer if you have malloced its own location, (but I guess I'm feeling annoyingly pedantic tonight:).

Comment: @ThingyWotsit you are not helping :D at least I get the point thanks guys

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: The job of the annoying nit-picker is already taken. But you are right :-)

Comment: @AliKurabiyeci: To do my job: You pass **the value** of a pointer (to a local pointer of the function). C is **strictly** pass-by-value; you should do some research about it, a good C book should explain this fundamental concept, it actually answers your question completely (at a general level).

Answer (score -2):

It frees the address c is pointing to. You could still use the pointer 'c', but that is dangerous and you should never do it.

Comment: so in this example it frees the malloced memory? right?

Comment: @Ali Kurabiyeci   Yes. The pointer is a local variable. The only way it could be 'discarded' is after you left the function where you defined it.

Comment: you never free an address. And using the value of the pointer after freeing the object invokes undefined behaviour. **This is not just "dangerous", but simply illegal**.

Comment: @Olaf, Indeed. It frees the memory addressed by `c` (the memory to which `c` points).

Comment: can i use the c pointer if i assign a new address to it by with malloc?

Comment: @AliKurabiyeci Sure. You can. The safest way to handle it is to immediately  set it to NULL after you freed the memory.

Comment: @Ali Kurabiyeci, Yes. It's not using the variable itself that's bad, it's dereferencing its value.